# CRV 2014 mpg issues

Tags: honda, crv

We bought a Honda CRV 2014 in January.

We are supposed to get 23 mpg but are only seeing 15 mpg.

We run it in eco mode and dont drive fast at all. So why are we getting such low mpgs?

What can I do? Is this case for lemon law? I live in PA (if that helps).

Comment: Some more information about your driving habits would be helpful: e.g., city start-stop vs. highway, hills / mountains / bridges, average speed, altitude, tire pressure, etc.

Comment: City, flat roads, 25 mph, philadelphia (not sure?), not sure what the tire pressure is currently but i do know that they are not flat. Ill get the tire pressure info up in few hours.

Comment: And how many miles do you now have on the vehicle? It might not be past break-in, but I don't see that causing that much of a difference. I'd think about 2-3 mpg better after break-in and not the 8 mpg difference you are seeing now.

Comment: Are you using e85 gas? Is it 2-wheel drive, or AWD?

Comment: I have the same problem here in San Francisco I usually get 19-20 MPG that is my average city/freeway. I only have 660 miles on the car.

Answer (score 1):

if most of your driving is in the city (stop/start)you will never achieve manufacturers claims.Take it for a spin on the freeway (not during peak hour)driving at a constant speed
and check your mpg. compared to manufacturers claims.Weight is also an issue (number of passengers/cargo etc..Accessories like roofracks/bullbars/towing mirrors all add up.So 
does driving with windows down or using aircon.Clean air filter regularly.Paper element
is the way to go